# Google indexation

Tags: wordpress, indexing, seo, lamp, robots.txt

I have a newbie question about Google indexation.
We created a web app on a LAMP stack, where the app and a wordpress landing page share the same server.
My question is: When indexing the landing page, will Google robots go through the login link and starts indexing the app and users accounts ? cause we don't want that.
I'm asking because I think if we use the robots.text file, it can mean that the most active and important part of the website will not be considered bt Google, and instead, every user who comes to the landing page and clicks "login" will be considered a bounce ?
What are the standards in this matter ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google bot would be unable to crawl users/accounts as it would have no way to login